# "".join() in python 3.7 not working inside def

Tags: python, function, methods

I'm trying to generate a unique password with a function. Everything works fine, except `"".join`. Help me see whats the problem in the code? Using Python 3.7.

My code:

```
import random
import string


def password():
    a = []
    letters = string.ascii_letters
    symbols = string.punctuation
    for element in range(6):
        a.append(random.randint(0, 10))
        a.append(random.choice(letters))
        a.append(random.choice(symbols))
    random.shuffle(a)
    print(''.join(str(a)))


password()
```

Comment: remove `str`, just use `''.join(a)`

Comment: Don't *print* the password, *return* it.

Comment: Without `str` I get error that says "expected str instance, int found" ?
And return makes no difference for `"".join()`. I've tried. 
Thank you both

Comment: `str(a)` is converting your list to string representation. use `map(str,a)` instead

Comment: ah, since the list contains ints, use `''.join(str(x) for x in a)`

Comment: YESSS, thank you. Both methods worked!!

Comment: voting to close as "answered in comments"

Comment: Yes, please @davedwards

Comment: @davedwards answered in answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `join` over `str(a)`, you are first converting the list to a string, and then joining over every character in the stringified list.

What you want to do instead is convert *each element* in `a` to a string. You should use a [generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension), like this:

```
''.join(str(x) for x in a)
```

Alternatively, you can use the built-in function [`map(function, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), which is useful in the general case when you want to return a new iterable containing the results of `function` applied to every element in `iterable`. So you would use:

```
''.join(map(str, a))
```

It's basically a matter of taste as to which you find more readable.